# Why can't a multimeter measure its own current and voltage?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, multimeter

Well I finally obtained another multimeter, so now I have a Mastech MS8226T and a Ben Electronic M92A. I decided to measure at which voltages would the low battery warning appear and how much current each of them consumes.

So here's my setup: Power supply->M92A->9V plug->MS8226T->other end of the 9V plug->power supply.

I used M92A to measure current and wanted to use MS8226T to measure voltage. Unfortunately, I couldn't measure the supply's voltage using MS8226T. I always got 0 V. When I swithched the meters, M92A would show voltage out of range for every scale.

So I decided to use the powered on meter to measure current and the second meter to measure voltage. I got zero as result on both meters, when I wanted to use them to measure their own curent consumption.

Why is that so?

**EDIT** 
Here are the schematics.
[image: first image]
 On this image, XMM1 is the meter measuring current and it is powered by its battery. Meter XMM2 is powered by the power supply V1. I used R1 as the meter's power plug. When I use MS8226T as XMM2 in such a set-up, I get zero volts on the supply. When I use the M92A, I get out of range on all ranges. The XMM1 meter shows expected values.

[image: second image]
On this image meter XMM1 is powered by its internal battery, is measuring voltage and shows expected values. Meter XMM2 is measuring current and reads zero. I'm using resistor R1 instead of meter's power plug here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the circuit used inside of the multimeter to create a virtual ground at approximately Vbat - 6.2V, or about 2.8V for a 9V battery; this basically means the COM terminal on the meter is at 2.8V relative to battery ground and readings will be offset by this.

I tried with another meter to measure its 9V battery - it read 6.08V, which is very close to the predicted 2.8V drop.

Comment: So, if I understand what you wrote corectly, the potential of the com port is potential of the - side of the battery plus 2.8 V. Now, if I connect the power supply as the meter's power source, the supply's - side is meter's - side. Since the voltge between ends of the power supply is around 9 volts, and the voltage between the com port and the - of the supply is 2.8 volts, I should be getting around 6.2 volts reading for supply's voltage, since the reference point is same for both com and supply voltage. I get zero at one meter and out of range for **all** scales on the second meter.

Comment: Also, while this would make an impact on voltage measurement, why would it afect current measurement?

Comment: @AndrejaKo, it would affect current measurement as that is just measuring a voltage dropped across a shunt resistor.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, am I understanding you correctly that you cannot measure the voltage across a power supply? It would be helpful to see a schematic/diagram as I am confused by your description.

Comment: @Thomas O OK. But that still doesn't explain zero reading on both meters. Since the reference is 2.8V, I'd expect current readings to be decreased proportionally.

Comment: @AndrejaKo. Overrange is usually indicated by exceeding the smallest range, probably 200mV-400mV, and is often clamped by diodes. If you are applying 2.8V to the ADC input of the main ASIC, who knows what it will read?

Comment: @Thomas O I addded images. The meter which is showing overrange has manual ranging.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I am confused about the second schematic. How is XMM2 measuring current?

Comment: @Thomas O Well, here's how I intended it to measure current: Current goes from the supply to the current input of the meter and the to the current output of the meter. After that, it goe into the meter's 9 V jack, goes out and then back into the supply. XMM1 is just measuring voltage and should be making minimal impact on the current measured.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, but it's just measuring the current through a 10k resistor.

Comment: @Thomas O On the image, I used the 10k resistor to represent the meter's 9 V jack (I just found out that it's called PP3 clip), because of the program's limitations. There is no 10k resistor in reality.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, so the 10k resistor is the battery connection for the other meter?

Comment: @Thomas O The 10k resistor is the battery connector of XMM2 on both pictures.

Comment: @AndrejaKo in which case that would put COM at 2.8V shorting that to V+ and that would essentially measure 0 as it is the difference between COM and V+ which the meter measures, which explains your zero reading.

Comment: @Thomas O OK, I think I understand and by the way, my mind is now officially blown.