# Connecting power supply to fan? Does it work?

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm all new to electronics and I was wondering whether or not [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Battery-Box-Case-Slot-holder-for-4-AA-4-AA-DC-Battery-6V-AKKU-/280858846391?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41647de4b7#ht_3190wt_1270) work.

That one, as you can see it has a black + red cable, can I connect it to [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pc-Brushless-DC-Cooling-Blower-Fan-12V-50mm-x-40-mmx10mm-4010-2-pin-Wire-/180840058246?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a1ae84d86#ht_2104wt_1037) Brushless DC Cooling Blower Fan 12V 50mm x 40 mmx10mm 4010 2 pin Wire?

And as you see in the 2nd picture, it has a white thing on the cables, can I cut that off and connect all the cables together and then, would the fan start working?

Comment: That 'white thing' it's a connector

Answer (score 6):

The battery holder is for 4 AA cells, which are 1.5V for alkaline, or 1.2V for NiMH. That's either 6V or 4.8V in total. The fan is a 12V. It may work at the lower voltage, though it won't blow very hard. AndrejaKo suggests to use a second set of 4 AAs to get to 12V, but you better get a 12V **DC** wall wart. Make sure it's DC! The 100mA the fan uses will drain your batteries in a day.
The white dingus is a connector, which you would use with a mating part, which you probably don't have. So you can cut it off, and solder the wires directly together.

Comment: Could you link me to something with a 12V DC Power adapter? When I search for it on eBay all I see are wall adapters (like those that convert EU->US adapters), how does that work?

Comment: @Peter - Sorry, that's what we call them here, you'll find them as "wall wart", like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12-VOLT-DC-WALL-WART-POWER-SUPPLY-MODEL-AD-121ANDT-/320867137697?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ab52bf8a1). Look for 12V DC. Current > 100mA is probably not an issue, most have at least 500mA.

Comment: How would I connect that thing into the fan? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter - it has a connector, though a different type than the fan. You could cut both connectors and solder the wires together, or find a [DC power socket](http://be.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KLDX-0202-A-LT/?qs=epXiFF%2fxuAFSl8gMuvmS3B6XPJzXlh6Nz9TKEQzjXRU%3d) for the wall wart.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe.

Usually the 4*AA holders are used to create batteries by serially connecting the 1.5 V (nominal) cells into a 6 V battery. The voltage drops with use and can go as low as 3.2 V in some cases when the battery is nearly depleted.

On the other hand the fan in its specifications has the 12 V input voltage and maximum current of 100 mA. It's more or less usual laptop fan and it may or may not start working at 6 V. Basically such fans need some voltage to start operating and then can work on lower voltage. The 6 V provided by the holder populated with fresh AA cells is on the lower border of the start voltage. If the cells aren't fresh, the fan probably won't start.

The solution to this problem is to get two such AA cell holders (or one for 8 AA cells). This would give you nominal voltage of 12 V at the fan and it should work fine.

About the connections part: Take two holders, connect red wire of one holder to black wire of the second holder. This will give you a 12 V battery and you'll have one red and one black wire free. Connect the black wire of the newly created battery to the black wire of the fan and the red wire of the newly created battery to the red wire of the fan. You may want to put a switch on the connection between the two red wires or on the connection between the two black wires so you can more easily turn the fan on and off. In addition to that, the lowest voltage you can expect from the battery now is around 6.4 V with no load. This should be enough to be sure that the fan will work until the cells are completely depleted.

And yes, you can safely cut the white connector from the fan, it's just there so you can plug the fan into a device which has the matching receptacle. If you don't have the receptacle, you don't need the connector.

Comment: I was just wondering whether or not the principal work, there are several holders for 12V on the bay aswell. Would black go to black and red to red? I mean, does + go to + or + to - ?

Comment: @Peter Refresh the page to see the newest version of the answer. If something still isn't clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much Andreja. Now I know something more. And as for the switch, can I just purchase a switch of eBay like http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-x-MOMENTARY-PUSH-BUTTON-SWITCH-DC-50V-0-5A-RED-KNOB-Free-Shipping-/250973270098?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a6f2c3052   and connect it? How do I do it? And can I also use a voltage LCD or something, and between what cables would that be? Sorry if I'm annoying.

Comment: This is the voltmeter I mean http://www.ebay.com/itm/Slim-DC-Digital-Voltmeter-Panel-DC-0V-to-99V-Red-LED-Panel-Meter-with-Ear-/140734934068?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20c474ac34  as you can see it has three cables, white, black, red.

Comment: @Peter Take a look at the description of the items. The linked item is a momentary pushbutton and not a switch. The difference is that when you press the switch, it holds its state until you press it again. On the other hand, the pushbutton will automatically return to its starting state as soon as the pressure is removed. Also I don't see what the initial state of the pushbutton is from the linked page. There are in general two states: normally open which closes the connection between pins when pressed and normally closed which opens the connection between the pins when presses.

Comment: What you need is something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Toggle-switch-SPST-On-Off-/180855813776?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a1bd8b690). When you flip the switch, it will turn on the fan and when you flip it in opposite direction, the fan will turn on.

Comment: In case of the switch, just instead of connecting the red and red wire together, connect one red to switch and other red to the remaining pin on the switch. You can also instead of red wires do the same thing with black wires and the effect will be same. As for the voltmeter, take a look at the features and wiring part. The red wire is the positive power supply wire and goes to red wire of the battery, the back wire is the negative power supply wire and goes to black wire of the battery and white wire goes to the voltage you want to measure.

Comment: Hello. If I do that, then there won't be any supply to the fan (the voltmeter part), right? And the white thing, where would it go more specifically, I didn't understand the part. The red and the black wire is already going to the thing I want to measure? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the voltmeter would work if the white pin is connected to the red wire of the battery though. I got an answer about that [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/9630/1240)

Comment: @Peter AS for the voltmeter connection, no. That's how amperemeters are connected. The voltmeter is like you said a dead end and its black wire goes into black of the battery and red goes into red of the battery. As for the switch, it actually has 4 pins. I assume that the two on the bottom (one is hard to see) are always connected together and the two on the top are also always connected together.

Comment: I'm wondering again, take a look at this http://www.ebay.com/itm/DPDT-ON-ON-FLAT-Shaft-Car-Boat-Toggle-Switch-3v-4-5v-6v-9v-12v-110v-120V-BF202-/290647071095?pt=Guitar_Accessories&hash=item43abea5977#ht_3222wt_1037  as you see in the 2nd picture or 3rd, it has 6 pins, does it mean it can turn on/off three things at the same time?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) list for switch names. The linked switch consists of two switches controlled by same lever. The center pin connects to left or right pin depending on the lever position. So you can switch 4  devices in total.

Answer (score 0):

Convention rules here Red is + so series connect two 6V compartments then 12V fan runs Red to Red and Black to Black.